# Could a frozen dishwasher line have ruined something?

Tags: drain, dishwasher, freezing

I had a frozen pipe under my kitchen sink and was able to get the hot water moving with a hair dryer but the dishwasher also has a frozen pipe.  I was able to warm that up and get that going, but when I ran my washer, it filled up with water and spilled out all over the place.  I shut off the water and got everything cleaned up and the water stopped running.  after all of that, I turned the water back on and it was pouring out into my basement.  did the freezing ruin something?

Comment: Is the drain frozen or partially frozen?

Comment: Frozen water lines have a tendency to "burst".

Comment: I know its a bit late, but did you check the drain pipe for clogs/ice? I'm willing to bet that a clogged drain is the cause of this overflow.

Answer (score 1):

> Could a frozen dishwasher line have ruined something?

### Yes

Are you kidding?  Water spilling out and even in your basement and you're asking if something 'could have been ruined'?  You're way past that point.

Freezing water breaks things.  It probably destroyed the pump in your dish washer and any fittings near by.

PROTIP: Don't let the next one freeze.

Comment: I would think the solenoid would be damaged well before the pump since the solenoid orifices are much smaller and under pressure.